# Button on cameraOverlayView not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, camera-overlay

I have the following `cameraOverlayView` that is working to an extent. When the `UIImagePickerController` is called the standard controls are not shown and the **'Take Photo'**  button and **logo.jpg** are shown as described in **ObViewControllerCameraOverlay**. The button functions in that it goes blue when pressed but my problem is that it does not call the action (the NSLog is simply for test purposes). Can anyone see what I might have done wrong?

```
@implementation ObViewControllerCameraOverlay

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame])
{
    UIImage *logo = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.jpg"];
    UIImageView *logoView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:logo];
    logoView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 240, 50);
    [self addSubview:logoView];

    UIButton *takePhotoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [takePhotoButton setTitle:@"Take photo" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    takePhotoButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 330, 320, 40);
    [self addSubview:takePhotoButton];
}
return self;
}

- (IBAction)takePhotoButton:(id)sender
{
NSLog(@"test");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like you've told your button to call `takePhotoButton:` when it's tapped. Try adding

```
[takePhotoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(takePhotoButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

after you've created the button in `initWithFrame:`